# How to create a new image from another - ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I haven't been able to find good answers for this, maybe I'm not looking in the right place, I thought I would check here. I am sure there are simple answers to this (provided that you know them, of course).

Let's say that I have an image that is 1000x2000. I want to use ImageMagick to take a region of this image (starting at 40x50, and of size 100x200) and create another image, with exactly the same dimensions as the region (i.e. 100x200). How do I do this?

And then, if I wanted to resize the original image to 800x1600, what is the command for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cropping out a region, try, ooh, I don't know, maybe `-crop`? (searching "imagemagick crop" will probably take you to the imagemagick crop page, http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/)

```
convert input.jpg -crop 100x200+40+50 +repage output.jpg
```

Here the `+repage` is to ensure that your output image is the size of the crop (as mentioned in the above link).

For resizing, try (want to guess?) `-resize` or -`scale` (and again, googling "imagemagick resize" would have brought you to http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/, and an excellent resource)):

e.g.

```
convert input.jpg -resize 800x1600 output.jpg
convert input.jpg -scale '80%' output.jpg
```

Comment: I understand the basic terms. I wasn't sure of the exact format, and I don't have the time to spend on looking for it at the moment. Thank you for the answer, the "additives" were unnecessary.